How to change drag preview of a styled component, using pragmatic dnd?
I'm using Pragmatic DnD and am looking at the method onGenerateDragPreview, but the docs don't really show any way to re-render the component being dragged in order to send a prop to my styled component (to change the style):
const Test = () => {
  const rootElement = useRef(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = rootElement.current;
    invariant(el);

    return draggable({
      onGenerateDragPreview() {
        // how to change the color state to get it to StyledTest as a prop?
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <StyledTest color={color}>Some text</StyledTest>
  )
}


The docs are a little sparse in this area. I only got it going through trial and error while looking at the examples in the repo.
There are three additional imports to make to set a preview. And some additional state you have to add to your draggble component for it to have a preview portal.
Here is stripped down version of the component to focus on the modifications required.

import { setCustomNativeDragPreview } from "@atlaskit/pragmatic-drag-and-drop/element/set-custom-native-drag-preview";
import { pointerOutsideOfPreview } from "@atlaskit/pragmatic-drag-and-drop/element/pointer-outside-of-preview";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

export type DraggableState =
  | {
      type: "idle";
    }
  | {
      type: "preview";
      container: HTMLElement;
    }
  | {
      type: "dragging";
    };

// ...

const [dragstate, setDragstate] = useState<DraggableState>({ type: "idle" });

// ...

        onGenerateDragPreview({ nativeSetDragImage }) {
          setCustomNativeDragPreview({ // import this 
            getOffset: pointerOutsideOfPreview({ // import this
              x: "5px",
              y: "5px",
            }),
            nativeSetDragImage,
            render({ container }) {
              setDragstate({ type: "preview", container }); // flicks to preview state
              return () => setDragstate({ type: "dragging" }); // next tick flicks to dragging
            },
          });
        },

// ...


{dragstate.type === "preview"
        ? createPortal(<StyledChipDragPreview>{label}</StyledChipDragPreview>, dragstate.container)
        : null}


It uses react dom to react a portal to an element that's referenced by the preview generator. This is set as react state, and presumably when its generated the preview it calls the next setState to cycle the component back to a dragging state.
The preview is it's own component which can have unique styling effects. In the image below the component styles are duplicated the only difference being transform: rotate(15deg); is added to the preview.
<StyledChip
  $dragging={dragstate.type === "dragging"}
  $isDraggedOver={isDraggedOver}
>
  {label}
</StyledChip>

<StyledChipDragPreview>{label}</StyledChipDragPreview>


